# Bring GameObject in front of GUI Texture

Tags: unity

I have a GUI Texture that dims the screen, however I want certain game objects to not be dimmed. I tried putting them in front of the GUI Texture, but it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: If you want something in front of a GUITexture, you'll need to create a second [Camera](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.html), disable its GUI Layer component, and change the camera's [depth](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-depth.html) so that it renders on top.

Comment: I did that, then I tried bringing the game object behind the main camera, but in front of the depth-only camera, but the object wasn't appearing. And if I tried changing the depths, then the GUI texture would disappear.

Comment: Make second camera skybox to don't clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the GUI texture hides everything that is not GUI, so I removed it altogether and put a semi-transparent black plane. Problem solved.